# Using $this with an anonymous function in filters

Tags: php, plugin-wp-seo-yoast, sitemap

Okay so I have a method within a class which looks like

```
$this->addToSitemap('page', $urls);
```

This is used to append extra pages to the Yoast Sitemap. Here 'page' is the type of sitemap within yoast and $urls are the new urls. This method looks like this

```
public function addToSitemap($type = '', $links = array())
{
    $CustomSitemaps = $this;
    add_filter( "wpseo_sitemap_{type}_content", function() use 
    (&$CustomSitemaps) { return $CustomSitemaps->parseLinks($links); } );
}
```

Now here I am using an anonymous function because I need to pass the `$links` variable to the callback.

I am using `$CustomSitemaps = $this;` because an anonymous function does not allow `$this`. But for some reason his is still not working. If i do this

```
public function addToSitemap($type = '', $links = array())
{
    $CustomSitemaps = $this;
    add_filter( "wpseo_sitemap_{type}_content", function() use 
    (&$CustomSitemaps) { var_dump($CustomSitemaps->parseLinks($links)); 
    die(); return $CustomSitemaps->parseLinks($links); } );
}
```

I see no nothin dumping on the screen. But if I do below `$CustomSitemaps = $this;` I do see it

Comment: As far as I'm aware `$this` should work inside an anonymous callback in PHP 5.4+. Is it not working for you, or are you targeting an earlier version? Are you certain that this is the issue? I notice that the filter name is incorrect, which would explain why your code isn't working. `{type}` is supposed to be replaced with the type of sitemap you're targeting, eg. `wpseo_sitemap_post_content`.

Comment: Well if you see I am using this method by `$this->addToSitemap('page', $urls);` I pass page as the first parameter hence the `{type}` in the hook becomes page. So the hook is correct

Comment: You're not using the type variable in the filter name though. If you're trying to put the variable in the string, you're missing the `$`. It needs to be `"wpseo_sitemap_{$type}_content"` for that to work.

Comment: thankyou!!! okay so now when i var_dump i see the dump but it is null. So for some reason the method `parselinks` is returning null

Comment: You don't need to pass by reference if it's an object, the `&` is unnecessary